# D3 not showing rect but circle works

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, d3.js, ionic4, ionic5

I am trying to plot bars charts in a ionic app with not much luck. But, when I replace bars with circle it shows me a circle. I guess I am missing some bar chart related property in my code that prevents to render my bar.

```
    this.svg = d3Select.select('#bar-plot')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', '100%')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + this.size.width + ' ' + this.size.height);

    this.g = this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' +
          this.margin.left + ',' +
          this.margin.top + ')');

    this.g.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(this.barData)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .style('class', 'bar')
        // .style('fill', '#3880ff')
        // .style('stroke', '#3880ff')
        .attr('x', (d) => -1000)
        .attr('y', (d) => -100)
        .attr('width', 10000000)
        .attr('height', (d, i: number) => {
            100000
        });
        // .append('circle')
        // .attr('r', 100)
        // .attr('fill', '#3880ff')
        // .stroke('stroke', '#3880ff')
        // .style('stroke-dasharray', 6);
```

So if I comment all bar chart / rect lines and enable all circle lines it works. The `bar` style class exists in my `css` file.
Any idea what is missing here?

Comment: Just to confirm, each bar is meant to include both a circle and a rect?

Comment: No, the circle I used from another working plot to test I at least see something - that the `svg` logic above the `rect` stuff works. All I see when I run as above is a blank div. With `circle` enabled instead of `rect` I see the circle.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misinterpreted the last bit. Are the rects in the DOM when inspecting the page? They should be, but with no height, you need to explicitly return a value in the arrow function when using curly brackets.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Another set of eyes. Fixed the return in the `{}` brackets and it works now :)